# Positioning a node relative to two other nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the following TeX code to draw 3 shapes using Tikz library.

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=red,ellipse,minimum height=1.2cm,minimum width=4cm,xshift=7cm,yshift=1cm] (q1) {};
    \node[draw=red,ellipse,minimum height=1.2cm,minimum width=4cm,xshift=7cm,yshift=-1cm] (q2) {};

    \node[circle,draw,minimum size=.5cm] (c1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is to position the circle shape exactly in the mid of 2 ellipses,but 2cm to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the syntax of the `calc` library to do this. However, if the point is to place the node between the left ends of the ellipses, something like

```
\path (q1.west) -- node[circle,draw,minimum size=.5cm] (c1) {} (q2.west);
```

would be better I think.

In the code below I also added a third way.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=red,ellipse,minimum height=1.2cm,minimum width=4cm,xshift=7cm,yshift=1cm] (q1) {};
    \node[draw=red,ellipse,minimum height=1.2cm,minimum width=4cm,xshift=7cm,yshift=-1cm] (q2) {};

    \node[circle,draw,minimum size=.5cm] (c1) at ($(q1)!0.5!(q2) + (-2cm,0)$) {};

% place node relative to west side of ellipses
    \path (q1.west) -- node[circle,draw,minimum size=.5cm] (c1) {} (q2.west);

% A different option, same result:
    \path (q1) -- node[blue,circle,draw,minimum size=.5cm,xshift=-2cm] (c1) {} (q2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```